# <pre> tag not formatting newlines/tabs correctly

Tags: html, css

I am currently in the process of updating a site to be more responsive/mobile friendly. I have everything working wonderfully with one exception, `<pre>` formatted code samples. The content is being served by a blog engine, and the difference is entirely between themes. Reverting to the original theme, everything worked great again.

Here is the original display of `<pre>` code samples properly formatted:

[image: Properly formatted code sample]

Here is the underlying element's markup as seen by Chrome:

[image: CSS elements]

After updating the CSS however, `pre` formatted code isn't displaying properly, instead it appears like this:

[image: Broken code formatting]

In Chrome, the CSS is virtually identical:

[image: Broken CSS format]

For some reason with the new layout/markup, I simply cannot get the formatting to work properly, even though the styles being applied to the pre tag are effectively identical.  I've tried setting `white-space: pre` and `white-space: pre-wrap,` at various levels with no effect. I added word-wrap to support resizing existing content down, removing or adding it has no effect. I've tried changing the `display: type`, the parent container, changing overflow types, etc. All to no effect. I simply can't figure out why the `<pre>` tags seems to be ignoring the whitespace settings.

FYI, the site link [is here](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/) if you are interested. The original CSS theme [is here](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/themes/inove/style.css), and the new CSS theme [is here](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/themes/GFS/style.css). You can see a screwed up source example [here](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2015/05/08/A-Closer-Look-at-the-BabylonJS-Game-Engine.aspx).

EDIT to add calculated CSS results, although it all appears to be minor formatting differences:

Good/old calculated:

[image]

New/broken calculated:

[image]

**EDIT -- SOLUTION**

It ended up being the Render() method of a MasterPage for a BlogEngine theme has logic to strip whitespaces from the rendered results.  So CSS and whitespace was a red herring, there was no whitespace to strip.

Comment: When trying to find out where some difference in styling comes from it makes more sense to look at the "computed styling" in your browsers development console, not at the shown rule set.

Comment: in the new stylesheet you're missing `blockquote, pre {..}` line 49

Comment: I intentionally removed that bit.  Even adding the global blockquote/pre styling back verbatim doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Don't use online/real path links to show us your code & problem... each time you modify the source or (hopefully) when you fixed.. the example and therefore the question will be useless for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the formatting in your example got messed up. The `whitespace` directives doesn't do anything, because there actually is no whitespace left to preserve. I downloaded your page and quickly added some newlines and tabs. Now the first few lines look correctly (just as far as I added formatting):

[image: The first few lines are now displayed correctly]

Here is the diff between the two versions of the html document: http://pastebin.com/KTh9BTGi (Ignore the "no newline at end of file" part). Maybe you added some code on the server that removes newlines and unnecessary spaces?

Comment: This was ultimately the answer.  The Render method of the master page for this theme was stripping characters out.  UGH...   Thanks for taking my blinders off and pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems any HTML tag was not closed properly on the new HTML Theme markup.
If you are editing your blog on the browser, copy/paste the html code into a great text editor with language syntax support and verify if syntax highlight gets crazy at some line.

Comment: It's actually effective all code samples, this is just one I chose at random.  The bracket/markup in the source aspx master page seem to all be terminated correctly.